# wrong index when scroll in UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, indexing

I am trying to index `UITableView` in my app like iOS Music App's Songs.

So i wrote following code.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arrayOfSongs count];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] count];
}
```

However when i index to `P` letter , it's still show `A` letter data like following pic.

[image]

It doesn't change when i index to another letter.

Is there anywhere i am wronging?

please help me.

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` seems off, shouldn't that return the number items in your array for the specific section?

Comment: So which value should i return bro? When i remove that property , error occur.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using an array for section index titles, you should also 'partition' your data into sections.

A pretty good tutorial can be found here: [How to use UILocalizedIndexedCollation to add a localized index to a UITableView (aka adding an A-Z index to a UITableView)](http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/230)